# What is the product/sum of two gaussian processes?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I cannot find anything about the calculational rules when working with gaussian processes. So, how do i calculate the mean and covariance of the product (and division) and sum (and difference) of two gaussian processes and when is the result still a gaussian process?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69134/when-is-the-distribution-of-product-of-two-normal-distributed-variables-near-nor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of two Gaussian processes will be Gaussian (this assumes *joint Gaussian*, which includes independence as a special case.)  (expectations sum, if independent covariance functions will sum also.)

But the **product** will not be Gaussian, see [Product of two gaussian processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129584/product-of-two-gaussian-processes)   and   [When is the distribution of product of two normal distributed variables near normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69134/when-is-the-distribution-of-product-of-two-normal-distributed-variables-near-nor).

Comment: So the sum of two _arbitrary_ Gaussian random variables is Gaussian? No need for joint Gaussianity etc?

Comment: Wll clarify!!!!!

Comment: So the resulting mean and covariance will be just the used operator applied to the corresponding hyperparameters? So, the resulting covariance is just C1+C2 when adding two gaussian processes?